# Get Path to Library loaded by P/Invoke call within C#

Tags: c#, mono, interop

Does anyone know if there is a way to get the path to the library loaded by a C# interop call?

For example, if I do:

```
[DllImport("R")]
private static extern IntPtr someFunc()
```

Mono (and I assume .NET) explicitly find the path the library is on.  Is there a way to obtain the path the library was found as a variable? (e.g. /usr/bin/libR.so or C:\Programs\R\R.dll")

Comment: More pinvoke, use GetModuleFileName() on Windows.  This of course doesn't port well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible.  The mono library does sophisticated loading, but does not store that information anywhere for later programmatic use.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the environment variables MONO_LOG_LEVEL and MONO_LOG_MASK for this purpose, this way:

```
MONO_LOG_LEVEL="debug" MONO_LOG_MASK="dll" mono YourProgram.exe
```

You can play with the levels to maybe get less info but still enough. More info [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Logging_Runtime_Events).

Comment: Thanks!  This is actually how I knew it had this information.  Any idea how to get it in the console (and not the command line?)

Comment: what do you mean with the console? I thought the console and the command line was the same

Comment: I don't think you can know that from managed land, maybe you could P/Invoke libmono to do it?

Comment: looking at the mono source it appears the library loading function dumps the information to the screen, but does save it anywhere for later retrieval.